# How to predict using glm in R?

Tags: r, glm, predict

So I have a glm that is defined like this

```
oring.glm = glm(oring.data$Damaged ~ oring.data$Temp, data = oring.data, family=binomial)
```

The data looks like this

```
Oring   Temp
1        15
0        20
1        30
```

I want to predict what happens to the Oring at a specific temperature

I've tried doing this

```
logodds = predict(oring.glm, list(Temp=31))
```

But this gives me a list of values, as opposed to a single odds value.

How do I get that?

Comment: If you adjust the formula to be `Damaged~Temp`, you'll get the expected behavior.

Comment: Check the example in `?predict.glm` to see how to set up `newdata` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct to assume that you DV is dichotomous, then I'd use the logit link function, and access the predicted value of my fit using simple indexing:

```
g=glm(y~x,family=binomial("logit")) #fit
predict(g)[1234] # gives the predicted value of y for the x=1234.
```